# Set the default image size of an embedded image to match the image's original size in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-text-editor

Is there any way to set the default image size automatically in Gmail to ensure it embeds any given image at its original size?

For example, a 400x400 image would retain the size 400x400 when embedded in an email and not be scaled down.

Comment: Related: [How can I email an unresized image via Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130366/88163)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no setting in Gmail for inserted images.

In fact, the only setting that has anything to do with images is simply whether to show them inline or to ask before displaying them.