# How can I email an unresized image via Gmail?

Tags: gmail, images, gmail-attachments

I'm trying to email as an attachment to my iPhone a large image from my PC via Gmail. Its original size is 3840 x 1080 pixels (5.57 MB). At first, when I received the image it looked very bad on the phone (for which I blamed the iPhone). But then purely by chance, I had to email a similar image to my PC. After which I realized that the image was badly cropped down to 1280 x 360 pixels when I received it.

Is there a way to make it stop messing with my attachments?

Answer (score 1):

After you drop your image into the body of an email, left-click on it and select **Original size**. This way the size, resolution and quality won't be anyhow altered.

[image: 0]

- tested with the image of a size **[5000×2000 px @ 14,2 MB](https://www.deviantart.com/killerack/art/Backgrounds-snow-mountain-5000x2000-672498700)**

Comment: I was sending it as an attachment and thus I didn't see that fly-over bar with that option.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I was sending it as an attachment"*

The [provided answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130372/117311) is true when adding/dropping an image directly into the body of the email but has nothing to do with attachments.
We electronically sent images to people all the time. We never had an issue like that before when sending as an attachment. There must had been something else there.

In any case -as an alternative- if still in doubt, you can use one of the many [free transfer services](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=transfer+big+files).

- [WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/)
- [TransferBigFiles](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/)
- [Filemail](https://www.filemail.com/)
- [pCloud](https://transfer.pcloud.com/)
- [transfernow](https://www.transfernow.net/en/)

*These services have become our standard electronic "courier" when it comes to any kind of file sharing big files*.